# ng-table sorting dont sort correctly

Tags: angularjs, sorting

i am working with ng-table and sort my table by a dropdown.

In my tableparms i have

```js
$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                                page: 1,                                    // show first page
                                count: 8,
                                sorting: {
                                    vPADate: 'desc',                        // initial sorting
                                    vs_hier1: 'asc'  ,                      // initial sorting
                                }
                            }, { ....
```

The Problem is, that i became Dates sort wrong. The Score of my sorting is:

```css
25.11.2013
23.11.2013
..
02.12.2013     <-- this must be on top
02.11.2013
..

   or by numbers

5111125
5111121
344434
2323
2111155
151515
...
```

Looks like it´s sorted by text.
Who can give me a tip how to enable a correctly sorting?

I have no idea how to build a function for that.

The angular function for sorting the columns is :

```js
app.factory.ngTableParams.orderByng-table.js?cdv=19:233

function () {
            var sorting = [];
            for (var column in params.sorting) {
                sorting.push((params.sorting[column] === "asc" ? "+" : "-") + column);
            }
            return sorting;
        }
```

Who has a idea how i can rewrite this function by datatype? All i want is sort the columns with the correct type and correct style.